# Twitter Bootstrap 4 version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am required to use Twitter Bootstrap 4 in the homework, but I searched for that version and didn't find it, is it the same as bootstrap 4 or there is a specific version for Twitter.

what I tend to use is this 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is the name of the product.

The creators worked for Twitter.

[Then they left](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2012/09/29/onward/) and stopped branding it with the company name.